# Convert tiny line-segments to Arc

Tags: graphics, polygon, clip

I have is a list of all points (`List <Vector2(x, y)>`) that make up the below-given figure.

I want to convert the tiny line-segments (grey portion) that make up the arc to Arc so the resulting figure has just arcs and lines.

To draw an arc I'd need the start and end points. What could be a good way to find them?

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If, like in your figure, straight lines are much longer that the tiny segments along the arc, just detect the starting and ending points of the arc(s), and pick an intermediate point. You will obtain the arc from the circumcircle of these three points, with a little of trigonometry.

In more complex situations (a mixture of arcs of different radii), you can consider building a plot of the direction of the tangent as a function of the curvilinear abscissa. (Estimate the angle from two nearby points.)

In such a plot, straight lines appear as horizontals, and circular arcs as obliques. You can decompose the plot using the Douglas-Peucker algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

I do it like this:

[image: curve radius]

1. **take/detect 3 points `p0(x0,y0),p1(x1,y1),p2(x2,y2)`**

   exactly as Yves Daoust suggest. In case your arc is in vector form then just take start `p0` and end `p2` points of the whole thing and any vertex from/near the middle `p1`.
2. **cast 2 perpendicular lines from the created 2 line segments mid points**

   in the image are those the red lines. So the lines in 2D are:

   ```
   pa(t1) = (p0+p1)/2 + t1*(y1-y0,x0-x1)
   pb(t2) = (p1+p2)/2 + t2*(y2-y1,x1-x2)
   ```
3. **compute the intersection point**

   so just solve linear system:

   ```
   (p0+p1)/2 + t1*(y1-y0,x0-x1) = (p1+p2)/2 + t2*(y2-y1,x1-x2)
   ```

   the resulting point `c` is the arc center. Radius is `r=|p1-c|`.